# (Has or Did) the service got extended?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

What is the difference between **has** and **did**?

Should I use

> "Has the service got extended?"

or

> "Did the service got extended?"

Here, *service* could be a product like Whatsapp or such.

Comment: It should be "get" for "did the service get extended." And the "Did..." sentence sounds more natural but I dont have anything better than that.

Comment: Has the service ***been*** extended. OR Did the service ***get*** extended. OR ***Was*** the service extended?

Answer (score 2):

The positive statement in present [perfect] tense is

> The service **has been** extended.

Note the passive voice.  When - doesn't matter, result - service is continuing.

What are other ways to say it?

> The service **was** extended. - *referring to an act of extending it, taking place in the past.*
>   The service **got** extended. - *same form, essentially, passive voice*.

Both forms while pointing to the act of extending the service in the past, state that *now* the service is continuing (at least colloquially).

So, if you want to form a question about the extension of the service, use any of the above.  The present perfect would give you

> **Has** the service **been** extended?

while the past would be

> **Was** the service extended?
>   **Did** the service **get** extended?

While all are grammatically correct, the latter is *the least* acceptable, and the former (present perfect) is preferred, I think.

Curiously enough, while "the service **has** got extended" sounds *plausible* as a replacement for *passive voice*, I don't find it used, and neither is the question form of it.